# creating a bowl shaped 3d object in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shapes

How to make a bowl shaped 3d object in unity3d?

I have used ProBuilder tool to create a sphere and and used the vertex mode to drag around to create a object somewhat like bowl but that's not the best way.

Any best way to do that?

[image: unity bowl]

Comment: You can use ProBuilder but it is intended to fast make simple shapes to be used as prototypes/placeholders. ProBuilder is more about to see how the "real" (3d software made) objects will look together and how the finished scene will "feel" before you commit to making complex 3d objects.

Answer (score 1):

Unity is not a 3d modeling tool. Thus creation of 3d assets is usually done in another software (e.g. Maya, Cinema4D, Blender) and the final asset is simply imported (e.g. as fbx file).

If it's just about a really simple bowl you could use a sphere, scale it and use a shader which renders front- and backfaces, but omits the upper half. (Though this seems unnecessarily complex for a bowl.)